# Errors running `bundle install --path vendor --binstubs on MacOs` command Lind

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I am following some install instructions so I can locally test a website.

The instructions say to do:

```
gem install bundler # Works fine
bundle install --path vendor --binstubs # Gives me deprecation errors and such
```

What is the correct way to do what was being done in this line: `bundle install --path vendor --binstubs`?

Full error:

```
[DEPRECATED] The `--path` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set path 'vendor'`, and stop using this flag
[DEPRECATED] The --binstubs option will be removed in favor of `bundle binstubs`
Could not locate Gemfile
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like all I needed to do was `cd` into the root of the repo I was trying to build and run `bundle config set path 'vendor'` then `bundle install`.